# Django: Check instance if it exists in User Database and save to App Model Database

Tags: django, forms, view, models

I this in my forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import DirectReferral, IndirectReferral

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.RegexField()
    referrer = forms.CharField()

    def clean_username(self):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']
    raise forms.ValidationError(_("The username already exists."))
```

**How do I check if the referrer instance exist in User Database?**

I did the code below but it has an error of `TypeError at /register/`

```
    def clean_referrer(self):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['referrer'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("User does not exist."))
        return self.cleaned_data['referrer']
```

I did also try to do this but I get an error of `string indices must be integers`.

```
    def clean(self):
        if 'referrer' in self.cleaned_data:
            if User.objects.filter(username=self.cleaned_data['referrer']).exists():
                return self.cleaned_data['referrer']
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("Referrer doesn't exist!"))
```

Here is my models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class DirectReferral(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    referrer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="direct_referrals")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.username


class IndirectReferral(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    referrer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="indirect_referrals")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.username
```

**How do I get the referrer instance data?**
Here is my views.py (Updated)

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username']
            )

            ref_user = User.objects.get(
            username=form.cleaned_data['referrer'])

            direct = DirectReferral.objects.create(
                name = user,
                referrer = ref_user
            )

             if DirectReferral.objects.filter(referrer=user).exists():
                indirect = IndirectReferral.objects.create(
                    name = user,
                    referrer = ref_user
                )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
```

Comment: define: "The problem is both get_directreferral and get_indirectreferral doesn't work"

Comment: your question isn't clear enough. But I guess what you want is to replace `if self.cleaned_data['referrer'] in User.objects.all():` to `if User.objects.filter(username=self.cleaned_data['referrer']).exists()`

Comment: @e4c5 on `clean_username` when the user register, the user is added to User in Django Admin but it doesn't add to my Models.

Comment: thank you for the clarification but I am afraid it doesn't make things any clearer. When you say added to the Models, do you mean that a record for a model instance does not appear in the database?

Comment: @e4c5 The model instance appear in the database but the problem is when the user successfully registered only the username is saved in the User database. What I want is to add both the username and referrer to DirectReferral and IndirectReferral database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
        )

        # Assuming form.cleaned_data['referrer'] has usernames. 
        # If it has pks then just use pk=form.cleaned_data['referrer']
        # You should wrap this in a try-except
        dr_user = User.objects.get(username=form.cleaned_data['referrer'])  
        direct_referral = DirectReferral.objects.create(
            user=user,
            referrer=dr_user,
        )

        # Wrap this in try-except as well.
        ir_user = dr_user.direct_referral.referrer
        indirect_referral = IndirectReferral.objects.create(
            user=user,
            referrer=ir_user,
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
```

Also, this looks like a job for post_save signals. Check them out here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: thanks for this. I did edit my code above base on this but I still get errors.

Comment: @ChrisTope What's the error message? Can you paste the same here?

Comment: Check the code above. I did use your code with some revision on my views.py. I tried it without the referrer, and the username was succesfully created in my model database. But when I added the referrer it got some errors like `TypeError at /register/` and `string indices must be integers`.

Comment: Nevermind. It's working now.  I just deleted the ['referrer'] in self.cleaned_data['referrer']. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
DirectReferral.name = username,
DirectReferral.referrer = referrer,
IndirectReferral.name = username,
IndirectReferral.referrer = referrer,
```

you have to create objects first and than assign the values like this:

```
direct_referal = DirectReferral()
direct_referal.name=....
....
direct_referal.save()
```

also from your code, it seems that you are assigning string to user object:

```
DirectReferral.name = username
```

here username is string and DirectReferral.name is User object. You have to get this user object first and than assign to referral's name.

```
direct_referal = DirectReferral()
direct_referal.name=User.objects.get(username=username)
....
direct_referal.save()
```